# Can someone help me solve all longest strings puzzle from CodeSignal?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function allLongestStrings(inputArray) {
    var currentLargest = 0;
    var largestStrings = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++){
        if(inputArray[i] > currentLargest) {
            currentLargest = inputArray[i].length;
            largestStrings = [inputArray[i]];
        } 
        if(inputArray[i] = currentLargest) {
            largestStrings.push(inputArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return largestStrings;
}
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. the goal is to return all of the largest strings in an array. is there an obvious error in my code? If you could explain it, that'd be great.

Comment: What does the `inputArray` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you missing `.length` on your if statements ?
And you are assigning something instead of testing a condition in your last if statement.

```
function allLongestStrings(inputArray) {
    var currentLargest = 0;
    var largestStrings = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++){
        if(inputArray[i].length > currentLargest) {
            currentLargest = inputArray[i].length;
            largestStrings = [inputArray[i]];
        } 
        if(inputArray[i].length == currentLargest) {
            largestStrings.push(inputArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return largestStrings;
}
```